# Accessing file handles across multiple threads in TCL

Tags: multithreading, file, tcl

I am using tcl version 8.5.

I have created a Itcl class `itcl::class C_LOG` inside which I have defined few private methods and one of them is `public method openLog {filename} {}` inside which I am performing a file open/append operation,

```
if { [catch {open $filename a} logFileId ] } {
    error $logFileId
}
```

Outside the class I have created a multithread program `public method userInfo` which will print the userinfo env value into the file already created above.

```
puts $logFileId $userinfo.
```

But I am experiencing a error `can not find channel named fileXXXX`

It seems that the issue is because I have created a file handle outside the thread and I am trying to access the same inside a thread, I'm not sure if this actually works, if yes,
kindly let me know how to carry the file handles/channels to inside a thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that hard, you have to transfer the file descriptor to an other thread:

```
::thread::transfer $otherThread $logFileId
```

Once you did that, you can only access it from this other thread.
If you want to log from different threads, I suggest using an own thread and sending the data that it should log to it:

```
set logThread [::thread::create]
thread::transfer $logThread $logFileId
# And to log something:
thread::send -async $logThread [list puts $logFileId $userinfo]
```

Comment: The thread that doesn't own the channel can wrap the `thread::send` call of the logger inside a method. (For logging, I'd be tempted to use `thread::send -async` since I wouldn't be interested in the result…)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

By doing thread transfer, would I be able to have control of the file inside all my threads that are running parallel and also trying to access the file parallel.

Regards, Sarvesh.T

Comment: no. Use my last example if you want to do something like that.