# Not able to get the file handler across threads in tcl

Tags: tcl

Is there a way to solve the below thread related problem?

1. In the main portion ( no thread yet), we are sourcing lots of files and one amongst them is a .tcl file with itcl class and objects defined.
2. In the itcl class, a file is opened and the handle of the same is stored in a variable.
3. I am creating a multiple threads and would like to use the same file using the same handle.
4. Variable name of the handle could be passed across threads using tsv::set and tsv::get commands. However, the handle as such is not passed to threads. it says "Channel not found" error.

Could you pls help me fix this problem.

Comment: Try ``thread::transfer`` to move a channel to a different thread. See http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/thread/doc/thread.html#16 (and this is probably a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168071/accessing-file-handles-across-multiple-threads-in-tcl )

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `thread::transfer` to *move* a channel between threads, you can't use the same channel in multiple threads at once (and please don't move server sockets at all); there is *no* `thread::copy_channel`. (Think about it: if you had the same channel in two threads and both had readable event handlers set, what would happen when the channel gets readable? There'd be a race condition. The same problem would exist with writable channels, though most code doesn't notice that as Tcl's default behaviour is typically Good Enough.)

To use `thread::transfer`, in the source thread do:

```
thread::transfer $targetThreadID $channel
```

In the target thread, *after the above code in the source has happened*, you can then access the channel as normal. Assuming you're in the top-most master interpreter of the thread (sub-interpreters are managed via `interp` as normal). In practice, you usually do a `thread::send` or `thread::eval` in the source thread after the transfer to tell the target's Tcl scripts that they are now in charge of the interpreter.

---

For logging, have one thread manage the log files and the other threads just send messages to the logger thread to have them written out. Hide the details inside a logger object (“real” in one thread, “thread-aware proxy” in the others) in each thread so that nothing else in your code knows what you're up to.

Comment: Hi Donal, Thanks a lot for your response. Could you pls explain more on how to create master interpreter and the sub-interpreters you have mentioned ("Assuming you're in the top-most master interpreter of the thread (sub-interpreters are managed via interp as normal"). Also, how to handle the situations when creating the file happens even before Threads are created where we will not be knowing what would be the Thread IDs so that it could be used in thread::transfer command - Or is it something like we should create Threads first and then only try for thread::transfer?